# How do I implement keyword searching in NHibernate 3 using LINQ?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have an entity that looks like this:

```
public class Media
{
    public virtual string Caption { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

What I'd like to do is provide the user with the ability to search on multiple keywords on the `Caption`, `Description`, and `Notes` properties. In other words, if the user searches for '**apple banana**', it should search through the three string properties to see if any of them contains '**apple**' and '**banana**'.

I tried the following LINQ statement as a test:

```
var query = new[] { "apple", "banana" };

// GetAll<T> returns an IQueryable<T>
repo.GetAll<Media>().Where(x => query.All(x.Caption.Contains));
```

But I'm getting an exception:

> ArgumentException: 'Object of type System.Linq.Expressions.UnaryExpression' cannot be converted to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression'.

I know that the LINQ provider for NHib 3.0 does not implement all of LINQ's features. How would I rewrite this LINQ query so that it's NHibernate LINQ-compatible?

Comment: Did you check the PredicateBuilder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind, even if you figure out how to do do what you want with Linq optimally, it's still essentially going to be translated into a SQL statement that by defintion is going to look like the following:

(Caption LIKE '%apple%' AND Caption LIKE '%banana'%) OR (Description LIKE '%apple%' AND Description LIKE '%banana%')..etc

Or of course, the sub-optimal method might result in returning every record and then evaluating the conditions locally.

My suggestion is to look into NHibernate.Search, which uses the Lucene indexing engine as a back end. I think it will be more in tune with what you are looking to do.

Comment: Thanks. Lucene would be a great solution if we had massive amounts of data, but for now our requirement is to be able to handle at most a few hundred rows with a very simple search feature.